# Append only working for first child - looping issue?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, loops

I have a for loop that appends an ordered list with a list item and a load of other info.

It works great for the first list item, however, the others do not populate/append.

I'm having trouble finding which part of my code is causing the issue:

```
  <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var artistID =$(".artist").attr('id');

            $.get("songs.php?id="+artistID, function(data){
                for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++){
                    $(".songs."+data[j].ArtistNumber).append(
                        '<li class="song">'+
                            '<a class="song-link" onclick="songClick();return false;" href="'+data[j].FileLocation+'">'+
                               '<p>'+data[j].Title+'</p>'+
                                '<small>'+data[j].duration+'</small>'+
                            '</a>'+
                        '</li>'
                    );
                }
            },'json');
        });
  </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit:

It turns out all I needed was a $(".artist").each(function(){}) wrapped around that.

I hope this can be of help to someone.

Comment: I hope songs.php gives more then one item?

Comment: Yes, it should display 4 results

Comment: Paste here the return value of `$.get` from console.

Comment: Can you please verify that by directly accessing songs.php?id=smaple?

Comment: You're appending stuff to a dynamic `$(".songs."+data[j].ArtistNumber)`. This syntax assumes all these elements already exist in the DOM : `$(".songs.1")`, `$(".songs.2")`, `$(".songs.3")` etc. That looks very frail to me.

Comment: Results are based on the ID e.g. songs.php?id=1 gives one result, songs.php?id=2 gives two etc

Comment: @JeremyThille They do exist in the DOM already

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: So each `$(".songs."+data[j].ArtistNumber)` is a `<ul>` that you hardcoded beforehand? Each one with a `class="songs 1"`, `class="songs 2"`, `class="songs 3"` etc? So you append one `<li>` to every `<ul>`. So if you get 150 results, you must have hardcoded 150 `<ul>` manually beforehand, each one with their classes, and each one containing one `<li>`. Does that sound good to you?

Comment: @JeremyThille Ah no sorry, I misunderstood. I'm new to this as you can probably tell. The ol are generated with <ol class="songs <?php echo $artistsRow['ArtistNumber'] ?>">

Comment: The same. You don't create 150 lists of one song. You create one list and you append 150 songs. My point was that the right way is to select one `$("ol")` and append many `<li>` which are list elements. You currently generate many lists, select each list and append one song to each list. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JeremyThille I see what you are saying, however, there should be many lists as there is a list of songs for each artist

Comment: Ha. But your `for` loop selects one list and appends one and only one item  to this list. This is why you get only one item per list.

Comment: See my complete answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many comments, I finally get your point. Here is how to proceed : you want a nested 'each' loop.

Since you did not provide any data structure, I will assume it looks like this :

```
data = {
    "123" : [
               {
                 "title" : "song 1",
                 "fileLocation" : "someURL",
                 "duration" : "2m45s"
               },
               {
                 "title" : "song 2",
                 "fileLocation" : "someOtherURL",
                 "duration" : "4m10s"
               }
            ],


    "456" : [
               {
                 "title" : "song 1",
                 "fileLocation" : "someNewURL",
                 "duration" : "3m20s"
               },
               {
                 "title" : "song 2",
                 "fileLocation" : "someOtherNewURL",
                 "duration" : "4m17s"
               }
            ]
}
```

I assume your data is an object containing key/values, each key is the artist number and each value is a list (array) of songs of this artist (represented as object with details).

and here's how to exploit the data :

```
$.each(data, function(artistNumber, songs){ // Iterating through each artist/songs pair. songs is an array

     $list = $(".songs." + artistNumber); // Select each list one by one in the dom

     $.each(songs, function(index, song){ // song is an object

            $list.append(
                        '<li class="song">'+
                            '<a class="song-link" onclick="songClick();return false;" href="'+song.fileLocation+'">'+
                               '<p>'+song.title+'</p>'+
                                '<small>'+song.duration+'</small>'+
                            '</a>'+
                        '</li>'
                    );
      });
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ojzvvk3/) in action.

Comment: Thanks, you have been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure about your DOM, I would need your HTML, but here is a try :

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var artistID =$(".artist").attr('id');

        $.get("songs.php?id="+artistID, function(data){
            for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++){
                $(".artist").append($("<ul />").addClass(data[j].ArtistNumber).addClass('songs'));
                $(".songs."+data[j].ArtistNumber).html(
                    '<li class="song">'+
                        '<a class="song-link" onclick="songClick();return false;" href="'+data[j].FileLocation+'">'+
                           '<p>'+data[j].Title+'</p>'+
                            '<small>'+data[j].duration+'</small>'+
                        '</a>'+
                    '</li>'
                );
            }
        },'json');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

And this still will not ,because you make selector for class,and this get first item with class artist,you need to change selector.Try this[each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)